# Remove the Document ID column when 'Viewing properties' of a document

Tags: 2010, document-library, document-id

I enabled the Document ID feature in my site collection as a test but now I no longer need it so I have disabled.

However, the files in my library still have the Document ID field when I 'View properties' of the document. I would like to remove this field/column. It is not possible to do this the usual way.

Can someone explain how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the past, I've used PowerShell to remove the Document ID column from a library or all libraries in a site.

Might try a script like this:

```
$web = Get-SPWeb -identity http://portal/site
$list = $web.Lists[“Name of List”]
$column = $list.Fields[“Name of Column”]
$column.Hidden = $false
$column.ReadOnlyField = $false
$column.Allowdeletion = $true
$column.Sealed = $false
$column.Delete()
$list.Update()
```

http://shipoint.com/2012/08/01/delete-columns-from-sharepoint-2010-listlibrary-using-powershell/

Answer (score 1):

This works for me using Office Dev PnP.

```
Set-PnPField -List "Library" -Identity "Document ID" -Values @{Hidden=$true}
```

This way it's no longer visible on the DispForm.